# unable to retrieve tor network settings

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, whonix

On whonix 9.6, I can't access the Tor network settings, getting this message "Unable to retrieve Tor settings. Please ensure Tor is running". I want to setup transparent proxying.

Comment: https://www.whonix.org/forum/index.php/topic,1015.msg7353.html#msg7353

Comment: does that link address your question?